# Calculate the training time of a ML algorithm based on CUDA cores

Tags: graphics-cards

How can I have an estimation on training time of a ML algorithm based on the number of GPU CUDA cores? I am about to buy a Desktop and I want to know what GPU is best concerning the money I am about to spend.

Comment: Can you add a buget for the gpu and what you expect from the gpu?

Comment: Around 900 - 1000 euros for the GPU. Train image ML algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest AI gpu under €1000 is probably the RTX 3060 ti, and if you are lucky, RTX 3070. I know, those are cards for $500 MSRP, but gpu shortage... (thanks scalpers and miners). High prices aside, these are really nice cards when it comes to AI, they can even run some AI models in real time (AKA DLSS). I don't know how they preform with training AI models, but I guess the performance would be similar.

Comment: Can RTX 3060 Ti go faster than google colab pro (not pro+) ? If somebody knows for sure...

Comment: Try to avoid cloud subscriptions if you can get good stuff locally. With cloud, you also have latency, which you maybe don't really want with big AI models